# How to install tools with gulp for Azure IoT?

Tags: azure, gulp, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am following the first tutorial (blinking example) for Adafruit Feather and have been stuck at the step:

Install the Azure IoT Hub SDK for your Arduino board by running the following command:

```
gulp install-tools
```

I am getting the following error and I don't know how to resolve it:

```
[16:26:50] Using gulpfile D:\PROJEKTI\NavIoT\gitSamples\iot-hub-c-feather-m0-ge
ting-started-master\Lesson1\gulpfile.js
[16:26:50] Starting 'install-tools'...
[16:26:50] Starting 'install-tools-java'...
[16:26:50] Finished 'install-tools-java' after 106 us
[16:26:50] Starting 'install-tools-arduino'...
 ... package 'arduino-1.6.11-windows.zip' already installed...
[16:26:50] Finished 'install-tools-arduino' after 711 us
[16:26:50] Starting 'install-tools-arduino-init-libraries'...
events.js:160
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Users\Darko ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onerror.NT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
```

Do you maybe know solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to retire the gulp things for Arduino devices. Take a quick look at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-huzzah-esp8266-get-started, which is the get started experience for Adafruit Huzzah ESP8266 with Arduino IDE. Gulp tools is convenient but it's easy to bring lots of new problems.

However, the new tutorial for M0 is still under writing. The ETA could be next week. If you are interested about the new sample code, you can visit https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-Feather-M0-WiFi-client-app